# Size of a CompressedImage

Tags: ros, compressedimage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a compressed image in a bagfile.
I am subscribed to the topic with :

```
    sub=rospy.Subscriber("irat_red/camera/image/compressed",CompressedImage,image_callback,pub_vt)
```

I want to get the width and the hight of this CompressedImage to using it in a callback.
What should I do

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271908/size-of-a-compressedimage/) by [Younès](https://answers.ros.org/users/29249/youn%C3%A8s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2017-09-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In general, subscribing directly to a CompressedImage topic isn't what you want to do; in C++, you would want to use the [image_transport](http://wiki.ros.org/image_transport) mechanism, which will handle decompressing it for you.

Unfortunately, that doesn't work in Python.  Your options are either:

- Run an [image_transport/republish](http://wiki.ros.org/image_transport#republish) node that will subscribe to the CompressedImage topic, publish it as an Image topic, and subscribe to that.
- Look at the `format` field of the CompressedImage message to determine the compression type, then use an appropriate Python library to manually decompress the image data and extract the height and width.

---

Originally posted by [preed](https://answers.ros.org/users/30363/preed/) with karma: 88 on 2017-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Younès](https://answers.ros.org/users/29249/youn%C3%A8s/) on 2017-09-30**:
I can't use republish since it is not recognized by my Ubuntu 16.04. How could I resolve this problem?

**Comment by [preed](https://answers.ros.org/users/30363/preed/) on 2017-10-02**:
It does exist in 16.04, although you might not have it installed.  Try `sudo apt install ros-kinetic-image-transport`.

**Comment by [Younès](https://answers.ros.org/users/29249/youn%C3%A8s/) on 2017-10-02**:
It was already installed in my Ubuntu. I used the command    rosrun image_transport  republish compressed in:=/irat_red/camera/image image_transport:=compressed raw out:=/irat_red/camera/image
It works